# xamarin.forms: Changing language at runtim doesnt affect UI Hi

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am having an app where the user picks his or her language:

I have two resources files, both of which work because I can see the text showing up in Xaml.

A short overview:

Eng Resource:

```
 <data name="Next" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>next</value>
    </data>

    <data name="German" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>German</value>
    </data>

    <data name="Arabic" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Arabic</value>
    </data>
```

The Labels:

```
<Label Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.German}"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                       Grid.Row="0"/>
                <Label Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.Arabic}"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                       Grid.Row="1"/>
                <Label Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.English}"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                       Grid.Row="2"/>
```

I know that they work, becaause when I change from one emulator to another (one in germany, one in england) the language changes automatically.

But I want the user to be able to change the language upon button click.

I tried:

```
 case "english":
                    CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
                    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
                    mainPage.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
                    break;
```

But the phone simply ignores the language change.

Any ideas why?

Comment: If I remember correctly try setting the `AppResources.Culture = new CultureInfo(culture);` or `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `LocalizationResourceManager` class that handles language changes and also will have a property with the translation. When the language changes it will invalidate that string so it will force the property to change.

```
 public class LocalizationResourceManager : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public static LocalizationResourceManager Instance { get; } = new LocalizationResourceManager();

        public string this[string text]
        {
            get
            {
                return AppResources.ResourceManager.GetString(text, AppResources.Culture);
            }
        }

        public void SetCulture(CultureInfo language)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = language;
            AppResources.Culture = language;

            Invalidate();
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void Invalidate()
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(null));
        }
    }
```

Instead of binding our strings directly to the `AppResources` class, a Translate Extension that returns a `BindingProperty` is used and binds to our new `LocalizationResourceManager`.

```
[ContentProperty("Text")]
public class TranslateExtension : IMarkupExtension<BindingBase>
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string StringFormat { get; set; }
    object IMarkupExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
    }

    public BindingBase ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var binding = new Binding
        {
            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
            Path = $"[{Text}]",
            Source = LocalizationResourceManager.Instance,
            StringFormat= StringFormat

        };
        return binding;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MultilingualXFSample.Views.ChangeLanguagePage"
             xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:MultilingualXFSample.Helpers">

         <Label  Text="{helpers:Translate SelectLanguage}" />
</ContentPage>
```

For more, you can check: [Mastering Multilingual in Xamarin.Forms](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/mastering-multilingual-in-xamarin-forms/)

And there is a sample here: https://github.com/CrossGeeks/MasteringMultilingualSample .

Comment: this works, however you need to adjust the namespaces (mainly in the xaml) and intellisense wont tell you what strings exist and which dont anymore. but its a good solution. i just havnt found a way to change strings that are set from code not from xaml...